# Regex not working in Cypress .should('include',/regex/)

Tags: cypress

Am trying to assert on a url which is something like https://subdomain.name.io/abc/#/.
and I want to check that the url is ending in /abc/#/

I am using

```
cy.url().should("include", /\/abc\/#\/$/)
```

but when I run this I get error

Timed out retrying after 5000ms: expected 'https://subdomain.name.io/abc/#/' to include //abc/#/$/

Comment: `cy.url().should("include", "/abc/#/")` as far as I know `include` doesn't accept regexp

Comment: you are right @TachibanaShin it was my mistake works with match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want `.should('match', /\/abc\/#\/$/)`.

The `should()` command uses chaijs underneath, and this is the documentation for [match](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_match)

```js
expect('foobar').to.not.match(/taco/);
```

Be aware that none of the examples show a trailing `/`, so even if the app has it, `cy.url()` may remove it.

Comment: Thank you , yes you are right regex worked with match . In my case cy.url() returns the trailing / as per cypress logs, but good to know that in some cases it might not